# how to subtract next values in one columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter, subtraction

gaess, I Want to subtract the previous values and next value (previous  - next) in one columns on Python dataframe. The example and the output like this :

This is the one column dataframe:

```
  | Gross_reserve|
  | ------------ |
0 | 1.202.170,21 | 
1 | 1.190.721,39 | 
2 | 1.179.354,33 | 
3 | 1.131.377,18 | 
4 |     ...      |
```

And then the output i want is  make a new columns called "cf_res_g" with the value like this :

```
  | Gross_reserve| cf_res_g |
  | ------------ | -------- |
0 | 1.202.170,21 | 11.448,82|
1 | 1.190.721,39 | 11.367,06|
2 | 1.179.354,33 | 47.997,16|
3 | 1.131.377,18 |  ...     |
4 |     ...      |  ...     |
```

so, if we do calculation is like this:
index[0] - index[1],
index[1] - index[2], etc

Comment: The input and the output looks very similar, can you please validate that they are correct?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @TomRon sorry i got error when i want to write the problem, i already fix it. Thankyou

Answer (score -1):

I think you are asking for a `diff`: [pandas.DataFrame.diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html).

Comment: I already use diff but the output in index[0] is NaN whereas i want the value in the index[0] is 11.448,82 like the example i made

Comment: `diff()` accepts a a period parameter which can be negative. So try using `diff(-1)`